# How to uninstall the IBM Containers Extension (ICE) CLI tool?

Tags: macos, ibm-cloud

I have been experimenting with working with IBM Containers in Bluemix using the IBM Containers Extension (ICE) CLI tool. For this I have also installed Python 2.7.9, Python pip, Python setuptools, Cloud Foundry CLI and then ICE CLI.

I would now like to remove these from my Mac machine.

- Python... not so easy to remove the updated version I had to install
- Cloud Foundry - easy, removed
- ICE - unknown how to uninstall

So again - my question is: how do I uninstall the ICE CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Containers CLI is a Python module that we installed with Pip we can uninstall it with Pip. Run the following.

`sudo pip uninstall icecli`.

```
[02:31 PM] jeff@macbookpro [~]>sudo pip uninstall icecli
Password:
Uninstalling icecli:
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli-2.0-py2.7.egg-info
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/__init__.py
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/__init__.pyc
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/__init__.py
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/__init__.pyc
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/app.py
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/app.pyc
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/commands.py
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/commands.pyc
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/extensions.py
  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/icecli/v2/extensions.pyc
  /usr/local/bin/ice
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled icecli
```